# Mediapipe gpu usage

Tags: python, mediapipe

I am using PC with RTX3060 and python 3.10 environment. Is there any way to validate that when I process frame with mediapipe , it will be done on the GPU? If it doesnt currently run on the gpu, how to do it?

I install cuda libraries in python

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)